# How to let client side sign the transaction and send it to blockchain

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, signature, ethereumjs-tx

This mint function is giving me this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: transaction could not be decoded: unsupported transaction type
```

And if I use `ethereum-js/tx` module to serialize and sign the transaction, it pushes me to sign it server-side. Is there any way to sign a transaction client-side? Thank you.

```
mint: async (json, account, contract, privateKey) => {
        const nonce = web3.utils.toHex(await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account, 'latest'));
        const value = web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.01', 'ether'));
        // const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Sepolia, hardfork: Hardfork.Istanbul });

        const transaction = {
            to: antr.address,
            from: account,
            value,
            gas: web3.utils.toHex('30000'),
            maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex('1000000108'),
            nonce: nonce,
            data: contract.methods.mint(JSON.stringify(json)).encodeABI()
        }

        // const tx = new Transaction(transaction, { common });
        
        const signedTx = await window.ethereum.request({
            method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
            params: [transaction]
        });
        
        // const serializedTx = tx.serialize().toString("hex");
        const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`${signedTx.toString('hex')}`);
        console.log(receipt);
    }
```